# a problem in comparing two arrays' elements

Tags: arrays, c, string

As-salam Alaykom.
In this code I am trying to print the number of recurrences of each alphabetic character of a specific paragraph like this :

```
a ----> "Number of recurrences"
b ----> "Number of recurrences"
and so on...
```

by using the *stricmp* function to compare two arrays' elements in each loop. But it doesn't print anything at all and 0 errors, what is the problem?!?!?!?!?

```
#inlcude <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void main()
{
    int i, j;
    int z = 0;
    char h, g;
    char y[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char x[620] = {"C is a general purpose computer programming language developed in 1972 by Dennis Ritchie at the Bell Telephone laboratories for use with the unix operating system... and more which is not visible in the image."}; 
    for(j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 609; i++)
        {
            if(stricmp(y[j], x[i]) == 0)
            {
                z++;
            }
        }
        printf("y[j] -------> %d", z);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Copy & paste the code itself into the question, as text.

Comment: `stricmp` expects strings, not `char`s. ENABLE YOUR COMPILERS WARNINGS.

Comment: After each inner for-loop initiate the value of z to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are comparing `characters` no `strings`.

In C, the strings are char arrays with a '\0' at the end.

For example:

This is a C char: `'C'`

This is a C string: `'C\0'`

`stricmp` is expecting two strings and you are passing two characters.

So to achieve the solution you need to compare the characters and your program is running.

`if(toupper(y[j]) == toupper(x[i]))`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void main()
{
    int i, j;
    int z = 0;
    char h, g;
    char y[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char x[620] = {"C is a general purpose computer programming language developed in 1972 by Dennis Ritchie at the Bell Telephone laboratories for use with the unix operating system... and more which is not visible in the image."}; 
    for(j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 609; i++)
        {

            if(toupper(y[j]) == toupper(x[i]))
            {
                z++;
            }
        }
        printf("y[j] -------> %d \n", z);
    }

}
```